# how to refresh the text inside growl messages for protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing, growl

I have been trying to test two scenarios, wherein, first, the user doesnt enter any password, and growl throws an error, and second, wherein the user enters wrong password. Both the scenarios throw an error message in a growl message box. 
The problem is in protractor, where I'm checking for the error messages. The first one passes, but second one fails.
Below are the two test cases:

```
it("should validate password", function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    emailElement.clear().sendKeys('admin@gmail.com');
    pswrdElement.clear().sendKeys('');
    element(by.css('.newRqst')).click().then(function() {
        browser.wait(function() {
            return element(by.css(".growl-item")).isPresent();
        }, 10000).then(function() { //waiting 10 seconds for the growl to appear
            expect(element(by.css("[ng-switch-default]"))
                .getText()).toBe("missing password parameter");
        });
    });
});


it("should throw an error for incorrect email or password", function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    emailElement.clear().sendKeys('admin@gmail.com');
    pswrdElement.clear().sendKeys('1234');
    element(by.css('.newRqst')).click().then(function() {
        browser.wait(function() {
            return element(by.css(".growl-item")).isPresent();
        }, 10000).then(function() { //waiting 10 seconds for the growl to appear
            expect(element(by.css("[ng-switch-default]"))
                .getText()).toBe("Wrong email or password");
        });
    });
});
```

This throws an error for failure as:

```
Expected 'missing password parameter' to be 'Wrong email or password'.
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings about a locator matching multiple elements?

Comment: @alecxe: yes, yes... I am...